# Am I vulnerable if the public has access to my customer IDs?

Tags: magento-1.7, security

I created a referral program that uses a custom referral link and it includes the customer ID. I assume this is bad practice, but what specifically did I open myself up to? (If anything)

Comment: Anything globalised can be vulnerable, so this means to anyone can use too.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst revealing such information doesn't seem ideal, I can't see that explicit knowledge of an ID in itself would be too damaging. After all, one can reasonably hypothesise that every store will have a customer with ID = 10 for example. By using it in this manner it would potentially allow people to work out what e-mail the ID links to, but I can't think of any attack vector that would become more possible with knowledge of a customer id. We're just talking security through obscurity (which is no security).

That being said you could presumably avoid exposing the customer ID easily enough by generating a new unique hash value and storing as a new customer attribute. This is probably the approach I would take, but I'm not really sure why. I think it would be more for reasons like, all referral codes would be the same length (if we're talking increment ID, this would be true anyway) and you wouldn't be able to tell how long somebody has been signed up etc. So not exactly security in itself, just more obscurity.

More than happy to be proved wrong if anybody can provide a POC where the customer ID allows an attack vector. But if there is one, it would be likely the ID could be brute forced in a matter of minutes even on a large database.